# Remove everything but leave numbers and dots

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

This code is designed to remove everything but leave numbers

```
a = "1.1.1.1"
b = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', a)
```

but i want to preserve dots as well.

Comment: Do you want b to a safe version of a, or do you need to split a into an array, e.g. b=[1,1,1,1] ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try out

```
a = 1.1.1.1
b = re.sub('[^\d\.]', '', a)
```

instead.  `0-9` can be replaced with `\d` because that matches all numerical characters, and the `\.` is necessary because the `.` character is a wildcard.

Comment: Great solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a='1.1.1.1'
>>> b = re.sub('[^0-9\.]', '', a)
>>> b
'1.1.1.1'
>>> a='comp.languages.python'
>>> b = re.sub('[^0-9.]', '', a)
>>> b
'..'
```

The `[]` means match only these characters.

The `[^]` means match all characters EXCEPT these characters.

`0-9` is 0123456789

`.` is . but be careful with . because outside `[]` it is often used to match any single character

Comment: No need to escape `.` inside character classes (`[...]`) because special characters lose their meaning inside character classes.

Answer (score 2):

Not using regular expression:

```
>>> ''.join(c for c in a if c.isdigit() or c == '.')
'1.1.1.1'
>>> a = 'hello.1.number'
>>> ''.join(c for c in a if c.isdigit() or c == '.')
'.1.'
```